# Stripping all ids in an HTML template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mustache, hogan.js

I have half an idea of abstracting HTML templates for an host-plugin system I'm building.

A plugin gives the host its HTML template (hogan.js compatible) in form of string. Since ids are not allowed (there may be more than one instance of a plugin), the host has to find a way to strip all the id attributes on HTML elements and / or transform them into classes.

Is there an easy way, **in the browser**, to take a hogan / mustache template and preprocess it to strip all the id attributes (or change them into class attributes) before compiling it?

Comment: Can you tell us what ou have tried

Comment: I have tried nothing yet :)

Comment: It will not be easy to process compiled hogan templates (you may need JS parser written in JS), but you can remove IDs from DOM after including each instance of plugin - with no success... HTML code with JS or CSS probably will break when you strip IDs if JS or CSS is referencing these IDs. So, the only good solution is to keep source code of plugins 'clean' manually.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be done better on server side.

On client side could be something like this (still needing to be more specified to which elements):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div[id]").each(function(){ // I used div element, you should be more specific in this selector
        var id_val = this.id;
        $(this).addClass(id_val).removeAttr('id');
    });
});
```

Comment: you missed a single quote..  here `$(this).addClass(id_val).removeAttr('id);`

Comment: That is, every element that has an id. And it should be done on the template before or after compiling it (working on strings, I guess), not on the already - done element.

Comment: @janesconference, yes. in my code it selects every div that has a ID. If you want every element, remove just the div text and add this code in the end of your html without the `.ready()` function wrap. This is a bit odd, and I cannot imagine where removing all id's would be a good solution....